# Is it possible to have a single .resx file in a .NET Core project?

Tags: c#, localization, asp.net-core, .net-core

The only [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization) I can find regarding localization in .NET Core only covers the case with one `.resx` file per class/view. Is there no way to have a single `.resx` with all string resources in it? At least one per project.

For example, I'm using `AddDataAnnotationsLocalization` to get localization of validation errors. If I have a ViewModel A that inherits some base properties from another ViewModel B, I will need two resx files `A.resx` and `B.resx` where both of them will have the strings from B defined.

It would help me a lot if it was possible to just put all strings in a single file.

Comment: I haven't done resource files in .NET Core yet, but it looks like the documentation covers what you want. The example in your documentation link that starts after the text "At the lowest level" sounds like what you're looking for.